# const tuple to tuple of consts?

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

If I have a tuple member variable where the types in the tuple are a parameter pack of a class template, I can apply a function to each object in the tuple with a static member function like this:

```cpp
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename... Tp>
static void apply_to_foos(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, F func)  {
    auto& foo = std::get<I>(t);
    func(foo);
    if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Tp))
        apply_to_foos<I + 1>(t, func);
}
```

so for example, if `foos_`is the tuple member variable, I could implement a member function over the foos via:

```cpp
void frobnicate() {
   apply_to_foos( foos_, [](auto& f){f.frob();} );
}
```

etc. however, if `frobnicate` had been const I run into the problem that `foos_` will now be const, and `apply_to_foos` wants a non-const tuple. So for example this won't work (if foos are some kind of containers)

```cpp
size_t size() const {
   size_t sz = 0;
   apply_to_foos( foos_, [&sz](auto& f){ sz += f.size();} );
   return sz;
}
```

I could implement an overload of `apply_to_foos` that takes a `const std::tuple<Tp...>&`, const_cast to a non-const tuple and call the original overload, but, well, then I am just casting away const-ness.

The annoying thing about it is that the only part of `apply_to_foos` that cares about const-ness is the signature. Everything else will work with const values as long the const-ness is respected e.g. the lambda will need to take a reference to const value, etc. If I could cast from a const tuple to a tuple of consts then I could implement the const overload like this:

```cpp
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename... Tp>
static void apply_to_foos(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t, F func)  {
    auto& tup_of_consts = const_tuple_to_tuple_of_consts(t);
    apply_to_foos(tup_of_consts, func);
}
```

and the `size()` member function would just work naturally ... I feel like there must be an easier way to handle this though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `const std::tuple<T1, T2>` to `std::tuple<const T1, const T2>` without making copies of the contained items.

You have two options for what you can do though:

#### 1. Deduce the type of `t` and sidestep the problem entirely:

```
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename T>
static void apply_to_foos(T& t, F func)  {
    auto& foo = std::get<I>(t);
    func(foo);
    if constexpr (I + 1 != std::tuple_size<T>::value)
        apply_to_foos<I + 1>(t, func);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e989b6c9daf2557)

With the type of `t` deduced, both situations will work.  If passed a `const` tuple then `T` will be decuded to `const std::tuple<...>` making the type of `t` `const std::tuple<...>&` and if passed a non-`const` tuple then `T` will be deduced to `std::tuple<...>` and the type of `t` will be `std::tuple<...>&`.  The only other change required is to use `std::tuple_size<T>::value` in place of `sizeof...(Tp)`.  Note that this also allows `apply_to_foos` to work with other types like `std::array` and `std::pair`.

You'll probably also want to apply perfect-forwarding to allow `apply_to_foos` to work with rvalues and preserve the value category of the tuple elements as well.  For example:

```
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename T>
static void apply_to_foos(T&& t, F func)  {
    func(std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t)));
    if constexpr (I + 1 != std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value)
        apply_to_foos<I + 1>(std::forward<T>(t), func);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfc2ec71de20fe49)

#### 2. Create a new tuple containing references to the original tuple's contents

Create a second overload of `apply_to_foos` that accepts a reference to a `const` tuple and creates a temporary tuple of `const` references to the original tuple's elements:

```
template<typename F, typename... Tp>
static void apply_to_foos(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t, F func) {
    std::tuple<std::add_const_t<Tp>&...> tuple_of_const = t;
    apply_to_foos(tuple_of_const, func);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98004b3c4e81cfea)

This will work fine, but it has issues with value category preservation.  The elements of a tuple rvalue will be passed to the callback function as `const` lvalues and can't easily be moved-from for example.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is an okay use of `const_cast` to pretend that your mutable parameter is const. It may be UB, I'm no expert.

Basically, put the logic in the const version for const-correctness. Then the non-const version calls the const version after casting away the `const` from the reference.

First, removing a const from a reference (might be a better way to do this):

```c
// badly named but turns `const int &` -> `int &`
template <typename T>
struct remove_const_ref {
  using type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<
      std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>;
};
template <typename T>
using remove_const_ref_t = typename remove_const_ref<T>::type;
```

Then, the const version:

```cpp
template <size_t I = 0, typename F, typename... Tp>
static void apply_to_foos(const std::tuple<Tp...> &t, F func) {
  auto &foo = std::get<I>(t);
  func(foo);
  if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Tp)) apply_to_foos<I + 1>(t, func);
}
```

And the non-const version, which just casts and calls:

```cpp
template <size_t I = 0, typename F, typename... Tp>
static void apply_to_foos(std::tuple<Tp...> &t, F func) {
  apply_to_foos(std::as_const(t), [&func](const auto &v) {
    func(const_cast<remove_const_ref_t<decltype(v)>>(v));
  });
}
```

Example:

```cpp
int main() {
  std::tuple thingMut = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  const std::tuple thingConst = {1, 2, 3, 4};

  apply_to_foos(thingMut, [](auto &v) {
    v++;
    std::cout << "mut frob: " << v << std::endl;
  });
  apply_to_foos(thingConst, [](auto &v) {
    // v++;  error: you cannot assign to a variable that is const
    std::cout << "const frob: " << v << std::endl;
  });
}
```

Comment: For what its worth, I like @Miles Burdnek's first suggestion better than mine :)